# Estimating risk difference using delta approach

Tags: r

I want to estimate the confidence interval using the delta approach; an image of an example model is attached [output of delta approach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6bLR.png). The intervals are very wide compared to the MLE or bootstrap [estimates for bootstrap approach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzQ5y.png). Can anyone suggest a way to derive the accurate CI's using the delta approach? Thank you

```
Mod1 <- Mod0 <- model.matrix(object)[subset, ]
  n <- nrow(Mod0)
  Nvec <- matrix(rep(c(1/n,0,0,1/n),each=n), n*2, 2)
  
  if (method == 'delta') {
    if (scale == 'linear') {
      df <- deriv( ~y/x, c('x', 'y')) # y depends on x
    } 
    
    out <- sapply(parm, function(p) {
      Mod0[, p] <- 0
      Mod1[, p] <- 1
      Mod <- rbind(Mod0, Mod1)
      allpreds <- family(object)$linkinv(Mod %*% coef(object))
      avgpreds <- t(Nvec) %*% allpreds
      val <- f(avgpreds)
      V <- sweep(chol(vcov(object)) %*% t(Mod), allpreds*(1-allpreds), '*', MARGIN = 2) %*% Nvec
      V <- t(V) %*% V
      dxdy <- matrix(attr(eval(df, list('x'=avgpreds[1], 'y'=avgpreds[2])), 'gradient'))
      se <- sqrt(t(dxdy) %*% V %*% dxdy)
      out <- c(val, se, z <- abs({val-null}/se), 2*pnorm(abs(val/se), lower.tail=FALSE), val + qnorm(cilevel[1])*se, val + qnorm(cilevel[2])*se)
      names(out) <- c(name, 'Std. Error', 'Z-value', 'p-value', ciname)
      out
    }) 
    out <- t(out)
    rownames(out) <- names(cf)
    return(out)
  } ## end if delta
```